# ComboBox Dependent filtering RowSource property error

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox

I currently ran into an issue where I cant get the data in a ComboBox to filter correctly. 
I currently receive a *Run-time error '380': Could not set the RowSource property. invalid property value.*

If i Filter the first ComboBox by 11503 It will throw the error leading back to

**Me.PhaseNumComboBox.RowSource =  "11503"**

PhaseNumComboBox Row Source is Data!C2:C50 and JobNumComboBox Row Source is Data!B2:B50

My data is also repeating so the jobnum will have multiple 11503, trying to show all Phases linked to that job number.

```
Private Sub JobNumComboBox_Change()

    Select Case Me.JobNumComboBox.Value
        Case Is = "11503"
            Me.PhaseNumComboBox.RowSource = "11503"
        Case Is = "11588"
            Me.PhaseNumComboBox.RowSource = "11588"
        Case Is = "11503"
            Me.PhaseNumComboBox.RowSource = "11503"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: RowSource should resolve to a range

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish this. Change the RowSource to Range gave me an error Method or data member not found.

Comment: If you want to show all values from ColC where ColB is (eg) 11503 then you'l need to either create a range which has only those values and set the PhaseNumComboBox rowsource, or clear the list and add the values one-by-one or as an array.